# Separate remote directory links from normal webpage links in an array for curl

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, regex, virtual-directory

I have around 10 links inside an *array* in **php** and i want the the **remote directory links** **only** such as `http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/` or `http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/`
 and **delete all normal links** from the array.
Also I cannot control the way i am getting links beforehand.

How can I achieve this?

```
$links=array(
    'http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/',
    'http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/',
    'http://www.google.com',
    'https://localhost/questions/stackoverflow',

);



/* filter the array to remove local urls .. What should i do here??*/
$links=array_filter($links,'filteritems');

/* debug output */
echo '<pre>',print_r($links,true),'</pre>';

output I want
------
Array
(
    [0] => http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/
    [1] => http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/

)
```

Comment: Can you show sample file with both types of links in them and expected results?

Comment: output page or php code? @EmacsUser

Comment: Are the links in the question suppose to be links, or text examples?

Comment: examples of the links that i want to keep inside array @chris85

Comment: @JimHawkins Thanks, but I know how to use stackoverflow

Comment: uups, sorry. While reviewing some postings I took your question with someone else one. Didn't mean to harm you

Comment: can you answer or forward this question to your friends? @JimHawkins it's really urgent

Answer (score 0):

As the question was devoid of examples and a clear statement of the nature of the links inside the array this might, or might not, help solve the problem.

```
/* ?? array of "links" ?? */
$links=array(
    'http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/',
    'http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/',
    'http://www.google.com',
    'https://localhost/questions/stackoverflow',
    'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/api/json/23/skidoo'
);

/* callback function to determine if local or remote url */
function filteritems($item){
    return $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']!==parse_url( $item, PHP_URL_HOST );
}

/* filter the array to remove local urls */
$links=array_filter($links,'filteritems');

/* debug output */
echo '<pre>',print_r($links,true),'</pre>';

output
------
Array
(
    [0] => http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/
    [1] => http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/
    [2] => http://www.google.com
    [3] => https://localhost/questions/stackoverflow
)
```